# How expensive is .getClass() in Java?

Tags: java

I'm in the process of porting over a certain data processing algorithm from Java to C++. The reason for re-writing the code is portability, it needs to run in environments where Java is not available. However, as a side benefit some performance improvement was expected.

Basically, the algorithm reads data from a graph made up of objects with pointers to each other and then computes a result. During the computation numerous object allocations are made, so perhaps this is responsible for the slowdown. The thing is, the C++ code currently runs about 10 times faster than the old Java code. This was really unexpected. I only thought I'd see an improvement of maybe 50-60%.

Unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to post the code here for analysis. It's several thousand lines, so I'm not sure how convenient that would be anyway.

The thing is, the algorithm is almost exactly the same. The only major difference I can think of is in Java there are many daughter classes of a single super class and if(object.getClass() == daughterx.class) is called many times during the computation whereas in the C++ code only one general class is used (since there are few code differences between the daughter classes) and a simple integer comparison is used eg. if(object->type == 15)

How expensive is the Object.getClass() method in Java? What exactly is happening at the low-level when this method is invoked?

Comment: @xlc0212 Neither are any of the other people that don't understand Java!  ;)

Comment: @cheeken it is depends on the JVM, without JIT, I remember I read from somewhere that Java is even slower than python

Comment: Honestly this sounds like a non-problem.  Is it worth your time to benchmark and profile your deprecated code?  Unless you've done that, there is no way to know that `.getClass()` is the bottleneck.  Guessing isn't a helpful way to debug performance problems, unless you can significantly reduce the overall complexity of an algorithm (i.e. going from an N-squared operation to a log-N operation), and your dataset is very large.

Comment: I'm using the Dalvik VM. Also, I didn't mean for this to turn into a thread to bash Java. It's really nice not to have to worry about includes or finding libraries for really fundamental tasks. I'm just curious about how .getClass() works.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham yes, it is a non-problem. That's why I'm asking here in my spare time rather than actually doing any profiling.

Comment: @mimicocotopus: Without profiling and benchmarking we're all speculating too :)  I think you might be on to something with suspecting the object allocation, though.  GC can also be expensive.

Comment: @xlc0212 The venerated "I remember reading" source is authoritative on these matters. Given what any benchmarks I remember reading say, unless the C++ code is highly tuned, the workload anomalous, or (the most likely) the Java code bad, you shouldn't be seeing an order of magnitude difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely case for a 10x difference is that the JVM wasn't warmed up completely.  If you don't do this you can see more than 10x performance difference even in Java.  I would try running in batches of 10,000 and ignore the first few runs.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    timeObjectGraph("First run", 1);
    timeObjectGraph("Second run", 2);
    timeObjectGraph("Next thousand", 1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        timeObjectGraph("Next ten thousand", 10000);
}

static int dontOptimiseAway = 0;

public static void timeObjectGraph(String desc, int runs) throws IOException {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        oos.writeObject(Calendar.getInstance());
        oos.close();
        dontOptimiseAway = out.toByteArray().length;
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("%s took an avg time of %,d ns%n", desc, time / runs);
}
```

prints

```
First run took an avg time of 37,509,488 ns
Second run took an avg time of 439,054 ns
Next thousand took an avg time of 185,242 ns
Next ten thousand took an avg time of 41,698 ns
Next ten thousand took an avg time of 19,981 ns
Next ten thousand took an avg time of 11,541 ns
Next ten thousand took an avg time of 13,451 ns
Next ten thousand took an avg time of 11,289 ns
```

From the first to the last run, the performance has improved by a factor of 3000x

Comment: Why do you use Calendar.getInstance()? First the question is about getClass method. Second Calendar is **heavy** class to create, so Calendar.getInstance() **expensive by itself**, not because getClass is called inside. I think this example is not correct or you should provide more clear comment.

Comment: @Cherry I used Calendar and ObjectOutputStream as these are both expensive for a short piece of code, this gives a realistic example of how much difference warmup can make for a significant amount of code.

Answer (score 16):

> How expensive is the Object.getClass() method in Java?

Based on my knowledge of how it is implemented in non-mainstream JVMs, it is cheap

> What exactly is happening at the low-level when this method is invoked?

Typically ...

1. Extract the class index from the object's header (2 or 3 instructions)
2. Lookup the class descriptor from the class index (2 or 3 instructions)
3. Fetch and return the `Class` object reference from the class descriptor (2 or 3 instructions)

> The thing is, the C++ code currently runs about 10 times faster than the old Java code.

I expect that the performance bottleneck is somewhere else.  You should try profiling the Java code before jumping to any conclusions as to why it was slower.

Comment: +1 While the lookup itself is cheap, it implies a significant design and performance issue if you have sequences of `if(getClass() == SomeClass.class)` It suggests you need to more OO Design or as the OP did, combine these classes so it can use a switch or the like for the functionality.

Answer (score 6):

It's not likely to be the sole factor in the performance difference.  Unfortunately, without a much more complete picture of what your code actually is doing, it's going to be really hard to tell you what's going on.

In my experience there's no reason Java should be 10x slower than C++.  I would probably start with a profiler and see where it points to understand the problem, rather than guessing.